# PHP Post operation always end with status 200

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to implement a simple PHP API.
It "works" - tests the data and create the object in DB, but sends some warnings and a status code 200.

database.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept");
header ("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-JSON");

function connect()
{ //...
}

$con = connect();
?>
```

create.php:

```
<?php
require '../database.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if(
    !empty($data->Name) && !empty($data->Login) && !empty($data->Password)
){
    $query = // ... 
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $create = $stmt->execute();
    if($create){
        http_response_code(201);
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product was created."));
    }
    else{
        http_response_code(503);
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create user."));
    }
}
else{
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create user. Data is incomplete."));
}

function real_post() {...}
?>
```

My Postman response (with valid data):

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in
<b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
<b>D:\Data\Dev\ASN\server\api\database.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
<b>D:\Data\Dev\ASN\server\api\database.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
<b>D:\Data\Dev\ASN\server\api\database.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
<b>D:\Data\Dev\ASN\server\api\database.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

{"message":"User was created."}
```

With "Status: 200 OK".
And the data is properly saved in the DB.
I've tried with invalid data too: same status, same warnings, and the "Jason" message is "Unable to create user. Data is incomplete".
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: tip: remove all the headers from database.php and only set them when you send the response. Not all content will be json like the error messages which are being produced.

Comment: Well one of them says that you're using a depreciated standard so fix that and that warning will be removed and as for the rest it seems like you're trying to manipulate some headers but doing so incorrectly, generally for APIs I would recommend some sort of a framework such as lumen, slim, wolff

Comment: Thanks Ainz-sama, I could make it works in local (test) with always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 and, but for the target version, I don't have access to php.ini (shared server).

Comment: Find a different shared server. Their configuration is bad. Even if you have 0 budget there's still better hosts and free tiers out there